# How do I convert/consume an external REST API response body from json/string to bean - I'm using Spring Boot-Maven

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, response

I'm trying to build a simple web app which sends a request to x-rapid api to retrieve information about covid cases in a country.

I am using Spring Boot Maven project and, in the RestController, I don't know how to take the response from the external API, turn it into a bean which I can later use its properties to have them displayed in a thymeleaf generated table on the html homepage.

This is the body of the response:
{"get":"statistics","parameters":{"country":"romania"},"errors":[],"results":1,"response":[{"continent":"Europe","country":"Romania","population":19017233,"cases":{"new":"+4521","active":156487,"critical":431,"recovered":2606660,"1M_pop":"148704","total":2827936},"deaths":{"new":"+35","1M_pop":"3407","total":64789},"tests":{"1M_pop":"1149360","total":21857638},"day":"2022-03-23","time":"2022-03-23T16:15:03+00:00"}]}

```
@RestController
public class CovidTrackerRestController {
    
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    
//RomaniaData class has been created to take in the relevant json properties and ignore the rest
//I want to use spring boot to call the setters of this class and populate them with the relevant
//json properties
//I'm thinking of later persisting this data to a mysql database
    @Autowired
    private RomaniaData romaniaData;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String showCovidInformation() {
        
        // connect to a covid database
                        
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=romania"))
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "mykey")
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        
        try {
            response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(response.body());
        
        //I need to transform the response from the X-RapidAPI from Json to Java Object to send it to my thymeleaf html page 
        // to be displayed in a table.
        
        // get the information
        String responseString = response.body();
        
        // format the information
        System.out.println(response.body());
                
        
        // send the information to html page
        return "/tracker";
    }
    
    private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.add("covid-193.p.rapidapi.com", "mykey");
        return httpHeaders;
    }
```

How do I transform the responseString into a RomaniaData object?

Comment: Continued post is here where I solve the mapping of json with pojo's - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598876/consuming-external-api-and-converting-from-json-string-to-bean-doesnt-initializ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert your JSON string into your `RomaniaData` you can use Jackson library, and in particular [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) class and its method [readValue()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)). If your Json has some unknown properties you can ignore them as described [Jackson Unmarshalling JSON with Unknown Properties](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties).
Also you can use an Open-source library MgntUtils that provides class [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) which is a wrapper over Jackson library anyway. With that class parsing your Json String would look like this:

```
RomaniaData romaniaData = null;
try {
      romaniaData = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, RomaniaData.class);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
   ...
}
```

The Maven artifacts for MgntUtils library could be found [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils), and library as a jar along with Javadoc and source code could be found on Github [here](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)

Comment: Thank you, using your dependency worked, partially. 

However, the issue I am facing now is that the object generated has null fields.... So I have to understand where that is coming from.

Comment: Possibly because of inconsistency between JSON field and your class property name. Lets say you have in your class a setter setMyFunnyProp() but in JSON you have a property named "myNormalProp". So "myFunnyProp" will not get populated by value from JSON's  "myNormalProp". You can annotate your property or setter method with @JsonProperty("myNormalProp") and it will tell the Json parser to populate your class property  "myFunnyProp" with value from Json "myNormalProp". See this link: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations

Comment: thank you but that is not it, my properties are already marked with JsonProperty for relevant connections. I believe my problem lies in the structure of my classes, they don't match with the structure of the json response so they can't be mapped. I have asked another question here and I am working on the solution now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598876/consuming-external-api-and-converting-from-json-string-to-bean-doesnt-initializ/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson Json Serializer

```
RomaniaData romaniaData = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, RomaniaData.class);
```

Comment: Thank you, it partially worked, I had to use the configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false) after new ObjectMapper(). 

However, the issue I am facing now is that the object generated has null fields... meaning they are not filled. So I have to understand where that is coming from.