# Consuming external API and converting from JSON string to bean doesn't initialize properties. NULL object attributes. Spring Boot, Maven

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, maven

This is the response I get from the API.

{"get":"statistics","parameters":{"country":"romania"},"errors":[],"results":1,"response":[{"continent":"Europe","country":"Romania","population":19016885,"cases":{"new":"+4521","active":156487,"critical":431,"recovered":2606660,"1M_pop":"148707","total":2827936},"deaths":{"new":"+35","1M_pop":"3407","total":64789},"tests":{"1M_pop":"1149381","total":21857638},"day":"2022-03-24","time":"2022-03-24T07:30:04+00:00"}]}

```
@RestController
public class CovidTrackerRestController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String showCovidInformation() {
        
        // connect to a covid database
                        
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://covid-193.p.rapidapi.com/statistics?country=romania"))
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "covid-193.p.rapidapi.com")
                .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "mykey")
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = null;
        
        try {
            response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                        
        // get the information
        String responseString = response.body();
        System.out.println(responseString);
        
        Response romaniaData = null;
        
        try {
            romaniaData = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                            .readValue(responseString, Response.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            
        
        // format the information
        System.out.println(romaniaData);
                
        
        // send the information to html page
        return "/tracker";
    }
}
```

And this is my Bean class which is annotated with @Bean in the configurator class alonside the RestTemplate bean. Other properties such as Cases, Deaths etc are configured same as Response class except being declared as @Bean in the configurator because from what I know once I declare a class @Bean then other references contained automatically become beans as well.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("country")
    private String country;
    
    @JsonProperty("cases")
    private Cases cases;
    
    @JsonProperty("deaths")
    private Deaths deaths;
    
    @JsonProperty("day")
    private String day;
    
    @JsonProperty("time")
    private String time;
    
    @JsonProperty("test")
    private Tests tests;
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
```

Comment: First of all you should not put api keys in stack overflow questions.

Comment: @DanSerb whoop nice catch! Forgot about they key.

Comment: Response class should be a POJO, why would you inject this using @Autowired?
Classes used to store entities or in this case a response, should not be beans, you should instantiate those per api call, so it should be a member of the actual method, not of the class. You don't need to declare these classes as beans.

Comment: The @Autowired line was left from an earlier try, I forgot to delete it. I reassigned the romaniaData reference to null lower and instantiate it in the try block. I have edited the question to remove the 2 beans. The result is the same, anyway.

Comment: Your `Response` is a only a part of entire response you receive from API. It represents only  single element in the `response` property(which is array as well) in the json, not the entire json.

Comment: Btw your API key can still be seen in the post history. I think it would be best to change it.

Comment: @Chaosfire thanks I changed it and deleted the old one. Could you please advise in an answer how to approach the configuration ? It's my first time attempting such an app after taking a Spring Boot course and I'm not sure how to proceed. Been researching for the past couple of days but no relevant resources available on how to consume external API's except from CSV files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your java class needs to be exact representation of received json. Let's call it `Wrapper`:

```
public class Wrapper {

    @JsonProperty("response")
    private List<Response> responses;

    public List<Response> getResponses() {
        return this.responses;
    }

    public void setResponses(List<Response> responses) {
        this.responses = responses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Wrapper{" +
                "responses=" + responses +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am omiting some properties - `get`, `results`, etc. It looks you don't need them. Then deserialization will look like this:

```
Wrapper data = null;
try {
    data = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
            .readValue("json", Wrapper.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(data);
```

Few notes:

1. If json property name matches field name in class, there is no need for `@JsonProperty`
2. For tests field annotation should be - @JsonProperty("tests"). Property is `tests`, not `test`

If you really want to throw the rest of the data, and only need `response` property, then you need to write custom deserializer and work the json tree. You can see how to do it in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897528/json-deserialize-in-java-for-different-type-of-variable-in-same-object/70903626#70903626), or [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization), for example. Like this you can parse the response json to your class, even if their structures do not match.

Comment: YEEESS it worked! Thank you so much, I've been labouring on this for the past 2 days, can't believe it actually worked! 

I see that I need to learn how to map multi level jsons to pojo's. Any recommendations on resources for this?

Comment: Gee @Chaosfire we gave very similar answers almost at the same time. +1 to you from me

Comment: @Art I am not aware of such resources, it was mostly practice for me. You can try lurking in the serialization and deserialization tags and try to research and answer questions, i learned a few things while answering.

Comment: @MichaelGantman Haha, yea, it does happen sometimes :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your class should be like this:

```
public class ResponseWrapper {
  public List<Response> response;

  public setResponse(List<Response> response) {
    this.response= response;
  }
  public List<Response> getResponse() {
    return response;
  }
}
```

And class `Response` is your class as you published it. Your class have to have the same structure as JSON

Comment: Response is array in the json, it's not gonna work like this.

Comment: you are correct, so the property needs to be a list. modifying the answer